# Setting a second VPN for working form abroad

Tags: vpn, ip, remote-desktop

I am working from home in Germany and I would like to work from abroad for some weeks, I have to connect to my company VPN before I even sign in to my company computer in order to access my desktop, I would like to know, if it would be possible to set up a VPN connection set in Germany with a VPN router, connect my company computer to that router through an ethernet connection, and then connect to my company VPN faking the german IP address so they do not know I am abroad. I do not know if this is possible, but would be so helpful if anyone can tell me something. Othe option I thought of was, maybe I can turn off the proxy once I log into my company computer and then install some sort of software like any desk to work remotely, then turn on again my proxy and work from abroad with my personal computer, but this option seems riskier since I have to keep my company computer running home. thanks a lot for any possible help! :D

Comment: A very easy way to get VPN chaining to work would be to set up your German VPN on your router, then connecting with your computer to the work VPN just like you're used to. But please think about the other possible ramifications of leaving the country without telling your employer and ways this might be exposed, especially if you're working with sensitive data and might be breaching data protection guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I can see different questions/problems here. One is on a purely technic point of view, is it possible and how? The other is about the risks of doing so. As the question was initialy asked on InformationSecurity, I will start by this second aspect.

Accessing a corporate network through a VPN often comes with an internal security policy. Willingly not conforming to such a policy might have severe consequences, not on a technical point of view but in real life. Long story made short, if you try to use the VPN from abroad while it is restricted to German addresses you are violating a security policy. In some companies, you could be fired for that.

This has an immediate consequence on the technical aspect. If the IT security team has correctly secured your company computer it may not even be possible, because most corporate VPN prevent the machine to be connected at the same time to the VPN and another network. In that case, and if you have no administrative privilege on the machine, it is a no deal.

Even if your are admin on your machine, it will be close to exploiting a security breach. Without knowing exactly how your machine and its VPN are configured, it is hard if only possible to guess where the breach is. Conceptually, you should setup a *gateway* at your home with the VPN on one logical interface and a second remote connection. Whether that gateway has to be the company machine depends on what the VPN application controls. In my company, the VPN only accepts remotes if they are member of a specific Active Directory domain. Hard to fake unless you are a domain admin... On the other hand, if you company only uses a vanilla OpenVPN, it would be easy to install a Linux of BSD box as a relay. But unless you are entitled to secure that relay at a security level at least equal to your corporate VPN relay you would be responsable for opening a new access point to the internal network. Whether you want to go that way it up to you...